# Overriding Self-Signed SSL Certificate Warnings with Electron

Tags: electron

There are two prior questions leading to this question (if you're interested):

1. [ssl-for-intranet-applications-deployed-at-multiple-companies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61819074/)
2. [distributing-ssl-certificates-to-all-browsers-in-an-active-directory-environment](https://serverfault.com/questions/1018020/)

In [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/), do you have the ability to override SSL certificate warnings that you'd typically get when using self-signed certificates via a modern web browser?

Typically, in desktop applications, you do not have to adhere to the strict online-banking-level certificate standards that web browsers warn about. The data I'm transferring isn't that sensitive.

As a matter of fact, one of the only reasons I'm moved my app from http to https, is because certain web standard APIs won't function unless the protocol is https. The [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) is one example.

Otherwise, the data I'm transferring over in*tra*net just isn't that sensitive. Yet, the browsers attempts to burden me (and my users) with Online-Banking-Level certificate authentication.

I'm trying to avoid this somehow and thought that maybe Electron could give me more client-side control for pre-approving my self-signed certificate. Is this doable in Electron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some trouble with `https` and untrusted proxy certificates and this in my `index.js`

```
// We have to deal with self-signed and therefore untrusted root certificates.
global.process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = '0';
```

It's an intranet application that never reaches out to the internet, so it's ok for me here.

Comment: Note that this disables any certificate verification. It doesn't just silently accept your self-signed certificate, it will silently accept _any_ certificate. For, as far as I understand, _all_ HTTPS connections. It pretty much disables security as far as TLS/HTTPS is concerned.

Comment: @marcelm It's perhaps a shame that this has to be an all or nothing solution, but it is also a shame to burden my users with warnings that confuse them and warnings they must always accept in order to do their work. If there is a more granular approach, that only permits the one self-sign certificate, that I'm intending to permit, then please post an answer.

Comment: There's an alternative but that's almost always 'too much' for the users. Because each user would have to do some configuration or trust you. We can set an env variable `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` that has a path to a `*.pem` file with all certificates that should also be trusted. So either the users configure that (... forget about it) or you bundle it with your app, but then they have to trust you that it include *only* the correct certs and not others also... I needed that to be able to update electron behind the company proxies...

Comment: @LonnieBest The more granular approach is of course to get a certificate, but I've said that plenty of times now already, and you seem unwilling to accept that. Sadly, I have no answer to offer you on this particular question. My comment that this answer has huge security implications still stands; if not for you, then at least to warn future readers of this answer.

Comment: @marcelm Please don't mistaken my exploration of all options as a rejection of your suggestion. After all, I may do exactly what you've recommended.